# How does $injector service inject itself in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

An AngularJS app depend on the $injector service to inject other built-in or customize services in controller,directive or other injectable things, but how $injector service inject itself,just like :

```
app.controller(function($injector,$scope){

//...

});
```

Comment: I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging into angular's source code, whenever angular compiles an element having `ng-controller`, it calls this function to instantiate the controller and injects all dependencies:

```
controllerInstance = $controller(controller, locals);
```

Inside the `$controller` method, it calls this method

```
instance = $injector.instantiate(expression, locals);
```

to instantiate the controller based on the expression, in your case is `function ($injector,$scope){}`:

Which in turn calls `invoke`, notice this code snippet:

```
for(i = 0, length = $inject.length; i < length; i++) {
        key = $inject[i];
        if (typeof key !== 'string') {
          throw $injectorMinErr('itkn',
                  'Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got {0}', key);
        }
        args.push(
          locals && locals.hasOwnProperty(key)
          ? locals[key]
          : getService(key)
        );
      }
```

This loop is to create all dependencies and store in the `args` array. For each loop, it checks for `locals` first (containing something like `$scope`,`$element`,`$attr` for the current element). The important function call to notice is the `getService(key)`:

```
function getService(serviceName) {
      if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName)) {
        if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
          throw $injectorMinErr('cdep', 'Circular dependency found: {0}', path.join(' <- '));
        }
        return cache[serviceName]; //angular run to this line for $injector service
      } else {
        try {
          path.unshift(serviceName);
          cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
          return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName);
        } catch (err) {
          if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
            delete cache[serviceName];
          }
          throw err;
        } finally {
          path.shift();
        }
      }
    }
```

In case of `$injector` service, when angular initializes the module, it creates an `$injector` and store in this `cache`.

This means that `$injector` does not inject itself, `$injector` is just another service in this service `cache`. Whenever angular needs to inject a service, angular will look in this `cache`, if the service does not exist, angular will create it. `$injector` is one of the first services in this `cache`

Comment: @jabez128: you could this answer as accepted if you think it's helpful. Thanks